# Guarantee std::shuffle returns unique sequence

Tags: c++, c++17, shuffle

Is there a way to guarantee that `std::shuffle` produces an output that is not the same as the input?

Below is a toy example where I was playing around with some old code that would shuffle the letters in a word except for the first and last. I noticed that for short sequences `std::shuffle` would "randomly" shuffle the letters to their original positions and produce undesired output. So to "fix" the problem I just re-run `std::shuffle` again.

In simpler terms, is there a way to avoid the while loop or is it just a quirk of `std::shuffle`?

```
std::string Scramble(const std::string& plaintext) {

    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 g(rd());

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << plaintext;

    std::vector<std::string> words{};
    std::string cur_word;
    while(std::getline(ss, cur_word, ' ')) {
        if(cur_word.empty()) continue;
        words.push_back(cur_word);
    }

    std::for_each(std::begin(words), std::end(words), [](std::string& word) {
        if(word.size() <= 3) {
            return;
        }
        auto old_word = word;
        while(old_word == word) {
            std::shuffle(std::begin(word) + 1, std::end(word) - 1, g);
        }
    });

    ss.clear();
    ss.seekg(0);
    ss.seekp(0);
    ss.str("");

    for(const auto& word : words) {
        ss << word << ' ';
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for a random shuffle that isn't completely random?

Comment: How would the original permutation be any less random than any other? I don't see how that would qualify as a "quirk".

Comment: This sounds like a related problem to the problem of generating unique "random" numbers from a range.

Comment: @BaummitAugen It just seems that with a small sample size, like four letters, it more often than not returns the original permutation

Comment: More often than not being? every 24 times?

Comment: @Casey No, certainly less often than not; it should return it 1/24 of the time. Anyways, the while loop is the simplest way to enforce this criterion. Any replacement of std::shuffle that guaranteed no identity shuffle would probably just involve a while loop itself.

Comment: @Casey With four letters, each permutation, including the original one should have a probability of 1/4!  = 1/24 (higher if the sequence is not unique). If you are seeing any permutation "more othen than not", that would be the problem we should be investigating.

Comment: Well [random numbers](https://xkcd.com/221/) are [hard to predict](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25). Sometimes...

Comment: What platform, and what compiler? GCC has historically had problems with `std::random_device`

Comment: Does it matter if a sequence is produced that has **ever** been seen before or is it only needed to be different from the previous sequence?

Comment: This seems like a case of just use the simple solution in front of you. Any other solution is most likely going to be more complicated to write.

Comment: @Casey: "*It just seems that with a small sample size, like four letters, it more often than not returns the original permutation*" If this is genuinely what is happening, then that is likely the fault of your RNG engine, not of `std::shuffle`. You may not be seeding it properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## No.

`std::shuffle` is working as intended and returns a random permutation of the given sequence. Even if it's the same as the input.

Re-rolling the sequence on undesired output is the simplest solution and more than likely what a "unique shuffle" would accomplish anyway.